# How to compare certificate thumbprint

Tags: c#, security, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I use the following code to get certificate (x.509) from file upload,
how should I compare this certificate ,i.e. I need to get the certificate thumbprint or something to compare it with other certificate and see if they are equal,
how should I do that ?

```
HttpPostedFileBase myFile = Request.Files[FileName];
byte[] cerFile = SecurityHelper.GetFileBinary(myFile);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do

```
X509Certificate2 cer = new X509Certificate2(cerFile);
```

and then

```
string tprint = cer.thumbprint;
```

to get its thumbprint.

Note that there is a constructor for `X509Certificate2` that takes a file path, if you can avoid doing the read into the array yourself.

Comment: Simple and useful. Good job! :)